Error checking out file. Branch type not found in vob
I'm fairly new to clearcase config specs, and I created a new dynamic view with my config spec, and when I try to check out a file, I get this error message. When I created the view, the view name is me_25.0_dev.
Error checking out V:\me_25.0_dev\KT\Source|KTApp\file.csproj, branch type me_25.0_dev not found in vob 
\KT and no global type definition can be found. Unable to create branch requested by -mkbranch option in config spec. Unable to check out file.

I created the dynamic view in home base using this config spec.  I went in file explorer to the file I wanted to check out,
V:\me_25.0_dev\KT\Source\KTApp\filename.csproj

, but get the above error.
This is using clearcase installed in windows 10.
I thought it would check out ok by adding this to my config spec (see comment below):
# Config spec for KP+ V25.0 DevBranch development.
element * CHECKEDOUT
 
include C:\Data\kx_dev_SaveSpace.txt
 
# Use the kx_v25.0_dev branch for Products.mdb.
element \Cont\Products\products.mdb /main/release/nightly/kx_v25.0_dev/LATEST
element \Cont\Products\products.mdb /main/release/nightly/LATEST -mkbranch kx_v25.0_dev
element \Cont\Products\products.mdb /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element \Cont\Products\products.mdb /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
# These VOBs stay on nightly.
element \Asse\... /main/release/nightly/LATEST 
element \Asse\... /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element \Asse\... /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
element \Borders\... /main/release/nightly/LATEST
element \Borders\... /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element \Borders\... /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
element \Cont\... /main/release/nightly/LATEST
element \Cont\... /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element \Cont\... /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
# You're not changing RB files are you?
element \RB\Packages\... /main/release/nightly/LATEST
element \RB\Packages\... /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element \RB\Packages\... /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
element \RB\... KX_DMD_B38.2_REL1
 
# These file types stay on nightly.
element *.doc /main/release/nightly/LATEST
element *.doc /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element *.doc /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
element *.docx /main/release/nightly/LATEST
element *.docx /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element *.docx /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
element *.mdb /main/release/nightly/LATEST 
element *.mdb /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element *.mdb /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
element *.xls /main/release/nightly/LATEST
element *.xls /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element *.xls /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
# Use the kx_v25.0_dev branch for the initialize_products files.
element \DP\Install\Database\DPS_initialize_products /main/release/nightly/kx_v25.0_dev/LATEST
element \DP\Install\Database\DPS_initialize_products /main/release/nightly/LATEST -mkbranch me_v25.0_dev
element \DP\Install\Database\DPS_initialize_products /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element \DP\Install\Database\DPS_initialize_products /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
element \KP\Install\database\KPK_initialize_products /main/release/nightly/kx_v25.0_dev/LATEST
element \KP\Install\database\KPK_initialize_products /main/release/nightly/LATEST -mkbranch me_v25.0_dev
element \KP\Install\database\KPK_initialize_products /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element \KP\Install\database\KPK_initialize_products /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
element \KT\Install\Database\KT_initialize_products /main/release/nightly/kx_v25.0_dev/LATEST
element \KT\Install\Database\KT_initialize_products /main/release/nightly/LATEST -mkbranch me_v25.0_dev
element \KT\Install\Database\KT_initialize_products /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element \KT\Install\Database\KT_initialize_products /main/LATEST -mkbranch release

element \KT\... /main/release/nightly/me_25.0_dev/LATEST   
element \KT\... /main/release/nightly/LATEST -mkbranch me_25.0_dev   #I thought this would fix it
element \KT\... /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element \KT\... /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
# Use my_developer_branch (or nightly) for Ret changes. 
element \Ret\... /main/release/nightly/mcleary_25.0_dev/LATEST
element \Ret\... /main/release/nightly/LATEST -mkbranch me_25.0_dev
element \Ret\... /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element \Ret\... /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
element \COT\... /main/release/nightly/LATEST
element \COT\... /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element \COT\... /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
# Use the kx_v25.0_dev branch for application changes.
element * /main/release/nightly/mcleary_25.0_dev/LATEST
element * /main/release/nightly/LATEST -mkbranch me_25.0_dev
element * /main/release/LATEST -mkbranch nightly
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch release
 
 
# Add Load rules for snapshot views below this line.
load \Ret
load \Ki
load \KP
load \KT
load \XL
load \DP
load \DPXL
load \Cont
load \COT
load \COT\DigilabsV2
load \COT\Realtek
load \COT\Gear
load \COT\Microsoft
load \Asse


I found out it wasn't working because the branch is frozen, as in they don't want people checking files out on this branch so turned off that ability.
